# Comment at the begin of a AngularJS directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems to be that AngularJS has problems handling comments in the first line of a HTML template.

Console gives me the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/tplrt?p0=deviceItem&p1=deviceItem.html
    at Error (native)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js:65:275
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js:112:113
```

So don't use a comment in the first line of an AngularJS directive, to avoid this problem.

Does anybody know why or is it simply an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link explains why this is an error:

> When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element.

Comments and text nodes are still elements even though they are not tags.  Thus you can't have this:

```
<!-- comment node -->
non-comment node
```

Angular can still use directives that are comments as well.

You can either not use `replace` as part of the directive definition or simply move the comment inside the root tag.  I don't think this is so bad:

```
<div>
    <!-- directive comments -->
    other things
</div>
```

Comment: Using replace in the definition of the directive does not help, but moving helps. Thank you for the enlightenment with the link in the error message. I did not realise that this explains the problem.